# Coordinator layout scrolling with unwanted parallax

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

So we have a 3 part app structure with 2 toolbars: 1 that is significant and should be always visible and 1 that is insignificant and should only be visible when user has scrolled to the top of page .the third part is a complex structure with nested view group, swipe to refresh, recycler view and some extra views . Note that we are not using the Collapsible toolbar or any other toolbar, but rather custom viewgroups.

I tried to achieve the behavior of toolbars with my current xml structure like this (notice the layout behavior flags) (PS: i cannot share the exact code,but would provide more details if needed)

```css
<Coordinator layout>
    <include layout=“xyz”>          <—     <appbarlayout>
                                            <linearlayout :layout_behavior:scroll|enterAlways …/>
                                            <linearlayout :layout_behavior:noscroll …/>
                                          </appbarlayout>

    <swipe refresh layout :  layout_behavior="....AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior”>

        <Nested ScrollView : mp/mp , fillviewport :true>

                <constraint layout : mp/mp>
                        <RecyclerView : nested scrollin enabled:false (via java code)>
                        <View>
                </constraint layout>

        </nested scrollview>
    </swipe refresh layout>, 


</Coordinator layout>

<!-- mp = match_parent -->
```

the result looks something like this( [gif](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19TmPqWRmvv9f-vwb_ELB6SfysP5GpRlt/view) / [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ldubwZOl9abvqThrmJoCoSfDEiZkoUjO/view?usp=sharing) ) (note the gif/video has some delay, please wait 7-8 seconds to see the action ) .

As you can see, the upper toolbar gets hidden when scrolled very hardly, but when scrolled slowly, the upper bar does not hide.

What can i do to fix this? i have tried changing the behavior flags as well as setting the heights as wrap content. I am guessing it is either due to wrong flags or due to complexity in bottom layout